# Can I still purchase after cart expired in Steam?

Tags: steam

I have received this email from Steam support.

> **There was an error with a recent Steam purchase.**
>
> We've saved your cart (including discounts) for 72 hours so you can attempt your purchase again.

If the cart has expired, can I still pay, if the payment method hasn't expired? The payment method involves scanning a barcode at a local shop, but gives several days.

So the barcode hasn't expired but the cart has. Can I still pay?

Comment: What code? Steam Wallet Codes? The Steam Wallet **Activation** Codes?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from just adding the games to the cart again?

Comment: @Studoku discounts won't be applied again